# get document link in gridview

Tags: document-library, spgridview

```
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:HyperLink ID="hlURL" runat="server" NavigateUrl="<%# Eval("LinkFilenameNoMenu")%>"
Text='<%# Eval("LinkFilenameNoMenu")%>'></asp:HyperLink>
</ItemTemplate>

using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
{
     SPList list = web.Lists["Documents"];
     SPQuery query = new SPQuery();
     query.Query = "<OrderBy><FieldRef Name=\"ID\" Ascending=\"False\" /></OrderBy>";
     SPListItemCollection listItemColl = list.GetItems(query);
     DataTable dtResut = listItemColl.GetDataTable();
     DataView dvReferral = dtResut.DefaultView;

     gvReferral.DataSource = dtResut;
     gvReferral.DataBind();
     ViewState["ReferralData"] = dvReferral.ToTable();
 }
```

The above is my code but when I click on the link of the document on the GridView it is navigating to some other page. I want to open the document in the browser or get option to save it to desktop and view the document.

Comment: Try and set target property of Hyperlink : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.hyperlink.target(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Where is it navigating? what is the url you are getting?